# How to enable Test Classes/Called in Assistant Editor of Xcode

Tags: tdd, xcode10.3

[image]

I want to know how to enable the area with red.

I found this post:
[Use Xcode's Test Classes Assistant Editor with Swift Classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34340997/use-xcodes-test-classes-assistant-editor-with-swift-classes)

> A file with a base name of FooTest or FooTests is now considered a counterpart of a file with a base name of Foo for navigation and the Assistant Editor. (28981734)

I tried, one file named Formula.swift, the other on in Test Projects named FormulaTests.swift, but not worked, do not show in assistant editor auto.

How to enable Test Classes/Called in Assistant Editor of Xcode quickly? Left is source code, right is unit test, that is what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My current method is open unit test file first, and then hold ctrl+option+command then click the Class in mouse, and the class will open in the right window of Assistant Editor, it is a long way, but OK.

I'm finding a short way.